# How to pass arguments when calling script after ssh

Tags: shell-script, shell, ssh

How can I pass arguments to install.sh script when calling it after ssh. This is how I call it:

```
declare -r SCRIPT_PATH=${BASH_SOURCE%/*}/install.sh;
ssh -tt ${!SERVER_ADDRESS} "$(cat $SCRIPT_PATH)"
```

Comment: Please comment here or on my answer if it doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're sending the *contents* of the script, I'd suggest you inject the arguments into it by using the `set` command to set the positional parameters:

```
ssh -tt "${!SERVER_ADDRESS}" <<END
set -- "arg 1" "arg 2" "arg 3"
$(cat $SCRIPT_PATH)
END
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! Finally, I am trying to solve this for 3 hours :D

Answer (score 0):

Same as locally;

```
ssh $SERVER install.sh argument
```

Comment: This doesn't work for quoted arguments, e.g.:
`ssh $SERVER test.sh "arg 1" "arg 2"`
-> This will run test.sh with the arguments "arg" "1" "arg" "2" instead

Comment: @ZleekWolf ssh $SERVER "test.sh \"arg 1\"" #it works.

Comment: Actually nice, but that again has it's caveates, if you run e.g. `ssh $SERVER "test.sh \"\$arg 1\" \"arg 2\""`, with the $ still being expanded as a variable. If you run `ssh $SERVER "test.sh '\$arg 1' 'arg 2'"` tho, it actually should be fine. Still, that's exactly the reason why I don't consider it working "same as locally", I think the answer should be extended with such info.